# Need help in regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

Can somebody help me how to change the below regular expression in such a way that it doesn't allow hyphen and Apostrophe in the first and/or last position. Any help is appreciated.

```
"[a-zA-Z][\\s-'a-zA-Z]{0,14}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z][\\s-'a-zA-Z]{0,14}(?<!['-])`

Comment: Won't work, as it forces there to be at least 2 alphas (1 at begin and 1 at end), while the original intention appeared to want to only enforce a single alpha at the beginning.

Comment: Doesn't allow whitespace as the last character, which I think is required?

Answer (score 2):

```
"[a-zA-Z][\\s'a-zA-Z-]{0,14}(?<!['-])"
```

`(?<!['-])` is a *negative lookbehind assertion* that requires that the character which precedes it not match `['-]`.

Answer (score 0):

Java regex patterns: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Perhaps something like this, my regex is not the best and may need to be corrected.

```
public bool checkStringForHorA(String s){
 s.matches("\\^(-'\\).\\^(-'\\)") ? return true: return false;
}
```

The regex should check to see if it starts with a - or ', or if after 0 to many characters . it ends with ' or -. If it does then it will return a true, if it does not then it will return a false.